# Spotify App publishing

Tags: spotify

I could not find anywhere on google information about Spotify Apps that would say anything about the future plans of this expansion, in particular, if it would be possible to publish your own app somewhere on the future Spotify App Store or something similar to that. Does anybody know if this feature is in the future development plans of the company?

Comment: Even if this is developer related, it's still offtopic.

Comment: this question is a software tool question. At least as I see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process for getting your application published on the App Finder is here:

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/process/

Specifically, we request you submit a concept to us first so we don't end up with duplicate apps, then once that's approved the process is fairly standard - you make the app, we make sure it's good enough for the App Finder, then it gets published.

If you've already started to make an app, no matter - just submit it as a concept anyway and we can work from there.